# How to plot a forceplot for every value in the shap_values

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, shap

I have trained a timeseries model using LSTM to predict the price of Ethereum.

I wanted to plot force_plots of each feature.

Following is the code:

```
import shap
def f(x):
        return LSTM_model.predict(x)
shap.initjs()
shap_values50 = explainer.shap_values(test_windows[0:50], nsamples=500)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values50[0][44])
```

The above code gets me a force plot for the 44th shap value, and likewise it gives me a output whenever I change the number 44 to anything in between 0-50 (as we have taken 50 samples in the test_windows)

I indent to print all the plots from 0-50. I tried to use a for loop for the same in the following manner:

```
for i in range(50):
       shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values50[0][i])
```

The above code dosent throw any error, but at the same time it doesn't give any output. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the plot on each iteration?

For example, try to see if something like this can work in your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(50):
   shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values50[0][i], show=False, matplotlib=True).savefig(image_path + '/forceplot_' + str(i) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
   plt.close()
```